# Group items in multidimensional array by same value at index

Tags: javascript

I have a multi-dimensional array like this:

```
var arr = [ [x,x,1] , [x,x,2] , [x,x,2] , [x,x,3] , [x,x,3] , [x,x,3] ];
```

and I want to make it like this (grouping each sub-array according to matching  `arr[i][2]` values):

```
var arr = [ [[x,x,1]] , [[x,x,2],[x,x,2]] , [[x,x,3],[x,x,3],[x,x,3]] ];
```

My attempts are getting increasingly long-winded, and I'm ashamed of posting them here. Any efficient suggestions greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array#forEach` solution.

```js
var arr = [["x","x", 1],["x","x", 2],["x","x", 2],["x","x", 3],["x","x", 3],["x","x", 3]], obj = {};

arr.forEach(v => (obj[v[2]] || (obj[v[2]] = [])).push(v));
var res = Object.keys(obj).map(v => obj[v]);

console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first group arrays by using one object and then use `map()` and `Object.keys()` to return array as result.

```js
var arr = [["x","x", 1],["x","x", 2],["x","x", 2],["x","x", 3],["x","x", 3],["x","x", 3]];

var obj = {}
arr.forEach(function(e) {
  if(!obj[e[2]]) obj[e[2]] = []
  obj[e[2]].push(e)
});

var result = Object.keys(obj).map(e => obj[e]);
console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var x = 'x';
var arr= [ [x,x,1] , [x,x,2] , [x,x,2] , [x,x,3] , [x,x,3] , [x,x,3] ];

var working = arr.reduce(function(acc, current) {
  (acc[current[2]] || (acc[current[2]] = [])).push(current);
  return acc;
}, {});

var result = Object.keys(working).map(function(k) { return working[k] });

console.log(JSON.stringify(result)); // stringified just to avoid scrolling
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and generate the new array with [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) in a single loop.

```js
var array = [['x', 'x', 1], ['x', 'x', 2], ['x', 'x', 2], ['x', 'x', 3], ['x', 'x', 3], ['x', 'x', 3]],
    grouped = array.reduce((map =>
        (r, a) => 
            (!map.has(a[2]) && map.set(a[2], r[r.push([]) - 1]), map.get(a[2]).push(a), r)
        )(new Map), []);

console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```