# Group javascript mutliarray by indexes and get sum and average

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a multiarray in Javascript with the following format

```
[ [string, string, string, number, number], ......]
```

For example

```
[
['John', 'Apple', 'Monday', 1, 4.5],
 ['John', 'Orange', 'Monday', 2, 3],
 ['John', 'Apple', 'Monday', 1, 2.5]
]
```

How can I group the above by the first three items (the strings) and get the sum of the first number and the average of the second number?

The result of above:

```
[
['John', 'Apple', 'Monday', 2, 3.5],
 ['John', 'Orange', 'Monday', 2, 3],
]
```

I used to do this with underscore, but now I need to use just Javascript or jQuery.

I found [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43158071/group-items-in-multidimensional-array-by-same-value-at-index) (not exactly) but didn't help a lot

Comment: is it possible to save the data as object from your side ?

Comment: This is the output of another function I wrote, so yes. As long as I can get it in the end as a multiarray instead of an object, I can change it in the meantime to an object.

Comment: can you please look at this link? https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/141530/calculate-average-of-array-of-objects-per-key-value-using-reduce

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could take an object and collect the values for later generating the average.

```js
var array = [['John', 'Apple', 'Monday', 1, 4.5], ['John', 'Orange', 'Monday', 2, 3], ['John', 'Apple', 'Monday', 1, 2.5]],
    result = Object
        .values(array.reduce((r, a) => {
            var key = a.slice(0, 3).join('|');
            if (!r[key]) {
                r[key] = a.slice().concat(1);
                return r;
            }
            r[key][3] += a[3];
            r[key][4] += a[4];
            r[key][5]++;
            return r;
        }, Object.create(null)))
        .map(a => a.slice(0, 4).concat(a[4] / a[5]));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Magic. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

One option is using `.reduce()` to group the array. Use `.map()` and `.reduce()` to get the total, average and construct the final array.

```js
let arr = [
  ['John', 'Apple', 'Monday', 1, 4.5],
  ['John', 'Orange', 'Monday', 2, 3],
  ['John', 'Apple', 'Monday', 1, 2.5]
];

let result = [...arr.reduce((c, v) => {
  let k = v[0] + v[1] + v[2];
  c.set(k, c.has(k) ? [...c.get(k), v] : [v]);
  return c;
}, new Map()).values()].map(o => {
  let t = o.reduce((c, v) => [c[0] + v[3], c[1] + v[4]], [0, 0]);
  return [o[0][0], o[0][1], o[0][2], t[0], (t[1] / o.length)];
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

The below may do the trick for you. I've left out the adding and average calculations, but the below structure of the code will do the matching of existing data.

```
const comparitorIndexes = [0,1,2]
array.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    const accIndex = acc.findIndex(x => comparitorIndexes.every(i => x[i] === curr[i]))
    if (accIndex > -1) {
        // Do sum and average here and return accumaltor
    } else {
        return [ ...acc, curr ]
    }
}, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = [
            ['John', 'Apple', 'Monday', 1, 4.5],
            ['John', 'Orange', 'Monday', 2, 3],
            ['John', 'Apple', 'Monday', 1, 2.5]
          ];
          
function groupData(data) {
  return data.reduce(function(acc, item) {
    if (item.length === 5) {
      var found = false;
      var lit = item.slice(0,3);
      var numSum = item.slice(3,4);
      var numAvg = item.slice(4,5);      
      for (var i in acc) {
        var accLit = acc[i].slice(0,3);
        if (accLit[0] === lit[0] && accLit[1] === lit[1] && accLit[2] === lit[2]) {
          found = true;
          var accNumSum = acc[i].slice(3,4);
          var accNumAvg = acc[i].slice(4,5);
          acc[i][3] = parseFloat(numSum) + parseFloat(accNumSum);
          acc[i][4] = (parseFloat(numAvg) + parseFloat(accNumAvg)) / 2;          
        }        
      }      
      if (!found) {        
        acc.push(item);        
      }
      return acc;
    }    
  }, []);
}

//function match

var result = groupData(data);
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nice and generic way, no matter how many duplicates you have, of doing it:

```
const arr = [
 ['John', 'Apple', 'Monday', 1, 4.5],
 ['John', 'Orange', 'Monday', 2, 3],
 ['John', 'Apple', 'Monday', 1, 2.5]
]

const newArr = arr.reduce((acc, curr)=> {
const key = `${curr[0]}_${curr[1]}_${curr[2]}`

if (!acc[key]) {
  acc[key] = [];
 }

acc[key].push(curr);
if(acc[key].length > 1) {
  const firstNum = acc[key].map(nestedArr=>  nestedArr[3])
  const secondNum = acc[key].map(nestedArr=> nestedArr[4])

  const sum = firstNum.reduce((a, b)=> a + b)
  const average = secondNum.reduce((a, b)=> (a + b) / 2)

  const newAcc = acc[key][0].slice(0, 3).concat(sum, average)

  acc[key] = [newAcc]
}
return acc;
}, {})
```

`console.log(newArr)`
Output

`{
    John_Apple_Monday: ["John", "Apple", "Monday", 2, 3.5],
    John_Orange_Monday: ["John", "Orange", "Monday", 2, 3]
  }`

I kept as a key_value because that might also help. But you can simply get the keys of that object with `Object.values(newArr)`